# Using MVC 5 web page to get data from outlook server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, outlook

I've had a look around and can't seem to find what I'm looking for (unless I have and didn't realise...)

I have been tasked with creating a basic CRM web based app so that it can be used on any device.

I am using MVC 5 to do this using SQL server to store all the required tables.

What I need to do know is be able to sync with an outlook exchange server so that the user can log in and their list of contacts/scheduled tasks are taken from the outlook information as well as be able to create/edit/delete etc the contacts + scheduled tasks and be able to post them back to the outlook server. ie without having to open a local Microsoft Outlook application.

Is this possible and if so does anyone know where I may be able to find a good enough source to help me learn this further.

thanks...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb408521(v=exchg.140).aspx

Comment: thanks for the link but again I may be missing something as the link you sent me has just gone right over my head...the first thing I need to is be able to get data from my existing outlook account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tewr's comment is right on the spot as this is a scenario suited for EWS (Exchange Web Services).

If you're using MVC 5 to develop this application, it may be the most helpful to use EWS Managed API to access the Exchange server as it allows you to all of it in C#.

Managed API - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220499(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220499%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

Working with contacts - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee693004(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee693004%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)